# How can I extract info from downloaded webpages?

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, grep, wget

I have to extract info like college name, contact number, email ids etc in a systematic order from thousands of webpages. Is there any script for doing it?

Complete scenario: I downloaded webpages containing individual colleges info using wget. There are about 5000 webpages about each college containing information of about them, however I am interested in just their name, email ids, website and contact numbers. And I need to have the extracted info saved in a suitable file in systematic order.
How can one extract info? How can I use grep to do it? Is there any better way of doing it? What scripts are available for pulling info? 
PS: I use Ubuntu and Kali linux. I am a newbie. Need expert's help.

Comment: have a look at python and BeautifulSoup

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have all files in one directory, "cd" to that and:

```
grep -i -e "Name" -e "email" -e "http" ./*
```

and improve that when you see the result. That will write into your screen, finally add after that:

```
>> my_collected_things.txt
```

to get it into afile.

Comment: It doesn't work. 
It gives output from the http source file and all of that are useless to me. 
I am a beginner in web development and python. I tried working with beautifulSoup and mechanize but couldn't write a script that would get the job done.